# How to show echo content inside of a DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce, echo

I am attempting to load an html file for inline editing with tinymce by basically echoing the output into a div area so the editor takes over. The page loads just fine, however the editor appears "above" the html page in what looks like a small div box that spans the page instead of the content. What I need is the echo'd $contents to appear inside of the div area and instead it seems to be appearing below it.

[image: screenshot added]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "div.edit",
theme: "modern",
plugins: [
    ["advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker"],
    ["searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking"],
    ["save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste"]
    ["fullpage"]
],
add_unload_trigger: false,
schema: "html5",
inline: true,
toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image     | print preview media",
statusbar: false
});

tinymce.init({
selector: "h1.edit",
theme: "modern",
add_unload_trigger: false,
schema: "html5",
inline: true,
toolbar: "undo redo",
statusbar: false
});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="edit"><?php 
$filename = "../projectevo/emeraldcity.html";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

echo $contents;

?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: have you been able to edit the html in `tinymce`?

Comment: No, the editor only appears in the small div style box above all of the html. I can click and highlight on all of the rest of the html but it is not editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use the Text area mode and it will work well.

```
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="100">
<?php 
$filename = "../projectevo/emeraldcity.html";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
?>
</textarea>
```

I have used this method and it works perfectly.

It should render something like this. And you could directly type to the table
[image]

And initialize like below

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
```

Instead of your

```
selector: "div.edit",
```

Comment: when I use textarea with the inline editing from tinymce it puts it in a text area perfectly with html, however tinymce does not load, it simply puts the html in the textarea box.

Comment: you have to replace your TinyMCe initialization code as mode : "textareas". I added that the explanation to the answer

Comment: I forgot to change the selector to textarea to put it in that mode, but that only gives the option to edit the html, instead of inline.

Comment: that worked perfectly Kasun after seeing your edit for allowing the edit of the html. 

However what I am wanting is for it to display the actual page, instead of the source html code and to edit it wysiwyg style (inline)

Comment: I'm not clear now, Do you need rendered html for wysiwyg editing or view the source code.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. like the screenshot I added above, I need rendered html for wysiwyg editing, which is what it seemed tinymce inline editing was capable of.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to get it to work. I wrote my <div> command wrong and needed to add a <div id="content"> comment after the <div class="edit"> command. Thank you for all of your help Kasun. Marking your answer correct.